# A question about Property Characteristics

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, ontology, protege

Say that I'm creating a vehicle ontology. A vehicle and its manufacturer is connected by something like `MyCar hasManufacturer Tesla`. Then the manufacturer has a country of origin which I specify as `Tesla hasCountryOfOrigin USA`. What I want is the `MyCar` to be connected to `USA` when I run the reasoner such that,`MyCar hasCountryOfOrigin USA`. I know that this is different from transitive property. How can I achieve this? (Using Protege specifically)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a [property chain](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-primer/#Property_Chains) in OWL. You want to define the chain `hasManufacturer --> hasCountryOfOrigin` as a subproperty of `hasCountryOfOrigin`. In Protégé, you can do it by selecting the property `hasCountryOfOrigin` (in the ObjectProperty tab), find the place in the lower right section with "SuperPropertyOf (chain)" and click the + sign, then in the new edit box that opens, type `hasManufacturer o hasCountryOfOrigin`. The property `hasManufacturer` must have been added previously. It's also possible to get the same inferences as a property chain with a SWRL rule, which can be done in Protégé, but SWRL is not a standard, whereas OWL and the property chain feature are.

Answer (score 1):

You have a rule like:

```
{ x? hasManufacturer y?; y? hasCountryOfOrigin z? } 
=> { x? hasCountyOfOrigin z? }
```

This might not be the right syntax.

Comment: That must be correct. However I want to do this in Protege. For transitive like properties, you can easily add the property in protege. What should I have to do in protege to achieve this? How/ Where should I add the rule?

Comment: I can't help you there. I haven't used that program. I just have a familiarity with some of the SW. Had watched it develop. Just could not get it yet to do anything personally useful.